# Lodash: _.has() returns false for last element in _.range()

Tags: javascript, lodash

Had a bug caused by this and while the fix is easy, (switch to `r.includes()`) I don't know why this occurred.

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

console.log("TEST");
var r = _.range(1, 10 + 1);
console.log("_.range(1, 11):    " + r);
console.log("Array.isArray(r):  " + Array.isArray(r));
console.log("_.has(r, 2):       " + _.has(r, 2));
console.log("_.has(r, 20):      " + _.has(r, 20));
console.log("_.has(r, 10):      " + _.has(r, 10)); // ???
console.log("x.includes(10):    " + r.includes(10));
```

Results in

```
TEST 
_.range(1, 11):    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
Array.isArray(r):  true 
_.has(r, 2):       true 
_.has(r, 20):      false 
_.has(r, 10):      false 
x.includes(10):    true
```

Why does `_.has(r, 10)` result in false? Is it a bug or am I just not understanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the values in the array are set by lodash as 1-10 (by your `_.range(1, 10 + 1)`), the keys of the underlying JS array remain 0 based.

You are effectively creating: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

`_.has` checks wether a path exists and in this case is looking for `r[10]`, but in the array above the last valid index is `r[9]` (since it's 0 based) So it returns `false`.

(Similarly, if you do `_.has(r, 0)` you will see `true`)

Answer (score 0):

`has` is used to check for a direct property of an object.
What you want to check is: If this array contains a value.
And this is answered by the Array method: `includes`.

### Reference

- [`has` from Lodash Document](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#has)